# How concatenate tuples in phantom types in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, hlist

I'm writing a SQL combinator which allows SQL fragments to be composed as a Monoid. I have roughly a type like this (this is a simplified implementation) :

```
data SQLFragment = { selects :: [String], froms :[String], wheres :: [String]}

instance Monoid SQL Fragment where ...
```

This allows to me to combine easily bits of SQL I use often and do things like :

```
email = select "email" <> from "user" 
name  = select "name" <> from "user"
administrators = from "user" <> where_ "isAdmin = 1"

toSql $ email <> name <> administrators
=> "SELECT email, name FROM user WHERE isAdmin = 1"
```

That works very well and I'm happy with it.
Now I use `MySQL.Simple` and to be executed it needs to know the type of a row.

```
main = do
       conn <- SQL.connect connectInfo
       rows <- SQL.query_ conn $ toSql (email <> name <> administrators)
       forM_ (rows :: [(String, String)]) print
```

Which is why I need the

```
 rows :: [(String, String)]
```

To avoid to have add manually this explicit (and useless) type signature I had the following idea :
I add a phantom type to my `SQLFragment` and use it to *force* the type of the `query_` function. So I could have something like this

```
email = select "email" <> from "user" :: SQLFragment String
name  = select "name" <> from "user" :: SQLFragment String
administrators = from "user" <> where_ "isAdmin = 1" :: SQLFragment ()
```

etc ...

Then I can do

```
query_ :: SQL.Connection -> SQLFragment a -> IO [a]
query_ con q = SQL.query_ conn (toSql q)
```

My first problem is I can't use `<>` anymore because `SQLFragment a` is not a `Monoid` anymore.
The second is how do I implement my new `<>` to compute correctly the phantom type ?

I found a way which I think is ugly and I hope there is a much better solution.
I created a `typed version` of `SQLFragment` and use phantom attribute which is a `HList`.

```
data TQuery e = TQuery 
               { fragment :: SQLFragment
               , doNotUse :: e
               }
```

then I create a new `typed` operator : `!<>!`  which I don't undestand the type signature so I don't write it

```
(TQuery q e) !<>! (TQuery q' e') = TQuery (q<>q') (e.*.e')
```

Now I can't combine my *typed* fragment and keep track of the type (even though it's not yet a tuple but something really weird).

To convert this weird type to a tuple I create a type family :

```
type family Result e :: *
```

and instantiate it for some tuples

Another solution would be probably to use a type family and write manually every combination of tuples

```
type instance Result (HList '[a])  = (SQL.Only a)
type instance Result (HList '[HList '[a], b])  = (a, b)
type instance Result (HList '[HList '[HList '[a], b], c])  = (a, b, c)
type instance Result (HList '[HList '[HList '[HList '[a], b], c], d])  = (a, b, c, d)
type instance Result (HList '[HList '[HList '[HList '[HList '[a], b], c], d], e])  = (a, b, c,d, e)
```

etc ...

And that works. I can write my function using the `Result` family

```
execute :: (SQL.QueryResults (Result e)) => 
        SQL.Connection -> TQuery e -> SQL.Connection -> IO [Result e]
execute conn (TQuery q _ ) = SQL.query_ conn (toSql q)
```

My main program looks like :

```
email = TQuery (select "email" <> from "user") ((undefined :: String ) .*. HNil)
name  = TQuery (select "name" <> from "user" ) ((undefined :: String ) .*. HNil)
administrators = TQuery (from "user" <> where_ "isAdmin = 1") (HNil)

main = do
       conn <- SQL.connect connectInfo
       rows <- execute conn $ email !<>! name !<>! administrators
       forM_ rows print
```

and it works!

However is there a better way to do it , especially without using `HList` and if possible less extensions as possible ?

If I "hide" somehow the phantom type (so I can have a real `Monoid` and be able to use `<>` instead of `!<>!`) is there a way to get the type back?

Comment: What's wrong with writing a secondary function `strQuery :: Connection -> Query -> IO [(String, String)]`; `strQuery = SQL.query_`, much like writing a function `readInt :: String -> Int`; `readInt = read`?  If you're always getting the same return type back, or just one of a handful of types, then this approach should be pretty manageable and doesn't require any fancy plumbing to work.  Otherwise I see no problem with having to specify the type inline.

Comment: in `(TQuery q e) !<>! (TQuery q' e') = TQuery (q<>q) (e.*.e')` perhaps  you meant `q<>q'`?

Comment: @bheklir: What's wrong in adding a type signature is that it's redundant and in theory unnecessary, each time I modify the query, I need to modify the type signature (If I need to modify something at 2 places it's redundant). Moreover, any type signature will type check but might fail at runtime. With my plumbery, once a column has been declared properly (which is done once and that I generated from the schema), every query combinations which type check will works. So it's basically "type" safer.

Comment: I am very confused by the `TQuery` type, the `!<>!` operator, and the `.*.` one, which I cannot find with hoogle. Could you explain?

Comment: @didierc: Hoogle doesn't work but Hayoo find it. `.*.` comes from HList , it's the heterogeneous version of `:`. Prepend something to a HList.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [haskelldb](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskelldb) which has the typed database query problem figured out. The records in haskelldb work fine, but they don't provide many operations, and the types are longer since they don't use `-XDataKinds`.

I have some suggestions for your current code:

```
newtype TQuery (e :: [*]) = TQuery SQLFragment
```

is better because the `e` is actually a phantom type. Then your append operation can look like:

```
(!<>!) :: TQuery a -> TQuery b -> TQuery (HAppendR a b)
TQuery a !<>! TQuery b = TQuery (a <> b)
```

`Result` then looks much cleaner:

```
type family Result (a :: [*])
type instance Result '[a])  = (SQL.Only a)
type instance Result '[a, b]  = (a, b)
type instance Result '[a, b, c]  = (a, b, c)
type instance Result '[a, b, c, d]  = (a, b, c, d)
type instance Result '[a, b, c, d, e]  = (a, b, c,d, e)
-- so you might match the 10-tuple mysql-simple offers
```

If you want to stay with HList+mysql-simple and duplicate parts of haskelldb, an `instance QueryResults (Record r)` is probably appropriate. An unreleased [Read instance](http://code.haskell.org/HList/Data/HList/Record.hs) solves a very
similar problem and might be worth looking at.

Comment: That's much cleaner indeed and pretty much what I'm looking for, althought I would prefer to get ridoff HList entirely. I've been considering `HaskellDB` as well as `Esqueletto` but none of them were quite what I need for what I'm trying to do, which is basically not have to specify the "from" clause and do auto-join.